# How to send keyboard interrupt to running program in shell mode?

Tags: shell, shell-mode

I wish to achieve what a `C-c` (send a keyboardinterrupt) would do in a terminal outside of Emacs. How do I do that in Emacs shell mode?

Comment: Please specify what that `C-c` behavior outside Emacs is, to make this Q&A more helpful for others. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Shell mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell-Mode.html#Shell-Mode) (and many other modes that run an external command interpreter), press `C-c C-c` (`comint-interrupt-subjob`). That's the `C-c` prefix of mode-specific commmands, followed by `C-c` which is chosen to be like `C-c` in a plain terminal.